# ноль с точкой после целого числа

Tags: python, float, int

Нужно чтобы число с нулем после точки — преобразовалось в целое число, при этом не затронув остальные числа.

Например, `27.0` должен быть как `27`

а `27.092` должен быть как `27.092`.

Таблица выглядит так:

```
p_num = {
    "1": {
        "py1": 9.02,
        "py2": 23.0
    },
    "2": {
        "py1": 105.0,
        "py2": 72.035
    },
    "3": {
        "py1": 193.4,
        "py2": 0.6
    },
    "4": {
        "py1": 37.0,
        "py2": 0.0002
    },
    "5": {
        "py1": 2.7,
        "py2": 500.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `is_integer()` для проверки.

В случае `number = 2.0` функция вернёт `True`, но в случае `number = 2.0019` мы получим `False`

В вашем случае это можно реализовать так:

```
p_num = {
    "1": {
        "py1": 9.02,
        "py2": 23.0
    },
    "2": {
        "py1": 105.0,
        "py2": 72.035
    },
    "3": {
        "py1": 193.4,
        "py2": 0.6
    },
    "4": {
        "py1": 37.0,
        "py2": 0.0002
    },
    "5": {
        "py1": 2.7,
        "py2": 500.0
    }
}

for key, value in p_num.items():
    for sub_key, sub_value in value.items():
        if isinstance(sub_value, float) and sub_value.is_integer():
            value[sub_key] = int(sub_value)

print(p_num)
```

Вывод:

```
{'1': {'py1': 9.02, 'py2': 23}, '2': {'py1': 105, 'py2': 72.035}, '3': {'py1': 193.4, 'py2': 0.6}, '4': {'py1': 37, 'py2': 0.0002}, '5': {'py1': 2.7, 'py2': 500}}
```

**UPD**

Если словарь имеет другую структуру (автор вопроса спросил в комментариях), то всё немного проще:

```
p_num = {"1": 9.02, "2": 23.0, "3": 105.0, "4": 0.6, "5": 0.0002, "6": 500.0 }

for key, value in p_num.items():
    if value.is_integer():
        p_num[key] = int(value)

print(p_num)
```

Вывод:

```
{'1': 9.02, '2': 23, '3': 105, '4': 0.6, '5': 0.0002, '6': 500}
```

Comment: в если список такой? `p_num = {
    "1": 9.02,
    "2": 23.0,
    "3": 105.0,
    "4": 0.6,
    "5": 0.0002,
    "6": 500.0
}`

Comment: @unzera обновил ответ

Comment: большое спасибо!